# UITableViewRowAction Cell with Corner Radius Changes Background Color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

When a UITableViewRowAction swipe happens the cell background associated with that action changes it's background color to white, instead of black like it typically is.  In other words, the color you can see behind the corner radius of the cell changes with the swipe action.  See example image below.

I've set the background color to everything to black on the View, TableView, Cell, so I'm not sure how this white is showing up. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome!

```
// Swiping Setup for TableView.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let dislikeActivity = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Don't Like This") { action, index in
        print("dislike button tapped")
    }        
    return [dislikeActivity]

}
```

[image: Cell with Corner Radius Background is White]

Comment: was the background colour set in interface builder or programmatically?

Comment: Did you change the content view background color of the cell? Or if there is any view overlapping the complete cell?

Comment: change tableview background color

Comment: Thanks for the questions to prompt ideas.  To answer the questions, background color was set in the interface builder and as was the view background.  I figured out what the issue was though...

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I changed background color of the cell to be default in the interface builder (xib) and set the background of the cell in the willDisplay Cell function noted below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 245/255, green: 250/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1)

}
```

Background of the tableView is still set to black in the interface builder.  I'm still not sure why that did the trick, but it did and it shows up properly now even with the corner radius.